# Firestore user roles

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I've made an app that utilizes Firestore. I am trying to find documentation on how to assign roles to my users. Ironically enough Google didn't help.

Time has come to set some security rules based on a users role. There will only be two roles; users and admin(s). Admins should be able read and write to everything but a user should only be able to read, write and delte its own content. Writing the rules for that is fine I suppose and well documented, but I can not seem to find any documentation on how to assign a role to a specific user. All my users are just regular users (I guess) including my own user. So adding the .isAdmin to a security check is kind of pointless.

Is there anyone out there that can point me in the right direction?

Comment: User roles are not really "feature" of Firestore.  Roles are only what you define, imposing your own structure on the database and [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication) to match, or user profiles in Firebase Authentication, using [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims).

Comment: See tip #3 and tip #7 in https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/03/firebase-security-rules-admin-sdk-tips.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Ill check out the admin SDK further. And by the looks of it, it seems that there is no support for iOS in that SDK? So you would have to create a website to run the code for the admin backend?